# Laravel Blade form money/currency format

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, integer, laravel-blade

I am building a form in Laravel (4.2) with Blade.

There are many options for input types. But, how do I set in input field set as an currency field? When I want to enter the money I paid for a product for example?

```
{{ Form::label('money', 'money:') }}
{{ Form::number('money') }}
```

I wanted the input field to become a number with a comma for separation and two digits after it:

€ |input field here|,|inputfield for digits|

I want it to display like.
€ 150 , 54

Can you tell me what to do, please? An explanation with link to some docs would be great! The Laravel docs at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#number aren't really helpfull

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the "Laravel" way of doing that, but if you're looking for a nice, clean way to show your customers the currency in a format you can than process on your server side i would recommend using jQuery formatcurrency:

Demo:
http://www.bendewey.com/code/formatCurrency/demo/

Docs & Download:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage

Than, if you want to make it a nice looking currency input on blur just use:

```
     $('.currency').blur(function()
            {
                $('.currency').formatCurrency();
            });
```

I know it's now perfect, but it worked for me and i loved it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! My programming style isn't the cleanest. I often look for hacks or other ways to do so, so this helps me a lot! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to from at a number or currency, is inside Laravel and PHP, JavaScript date and time formatting can change depending on the local settings.

You can create a Laravel Custom Blade Directives in your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider file.

Inside the boot function of your AppServiceProvider class add

```
\Blade::directive('convert', function ($value) {
    return "<?php echo number_format($value, 2); ?>";
});
```

Then inside of your blade templates you will be able to use

```
@convert(293)
```

Which returns 293.00

[number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

[Laravel Custom Blade Directive](https://laravel.com/docs/blade#custom-if-statements)